# MySQL WHERE after SET giving Error Code 1054: unknown column

Tags: mysql

I have two simple databases, 'rawdosingjune' and 'Dosage_June'.

The following SELECT statement returns the correct data:

```
SELECT * FROM rawdosingjune WHERE rawdosingjune.corrosion = 'TRUE';
```

However, if I put the same WHERE condition into an UPDATE statement I get an error?

```
UPDATE Dosage_June SET Corrosion_Basis = rawdosingjune.DosageBasis 
 WHERE rawdosingjune.corrosion = 'TRUE';
```

> Error code: 1054. unknown column 'rawdosingjune.corrosion' in 'where clause'

I have tried a number of combinations including creating the tables again?

These are the two tables

rawdosingjune:
[image: Dosage_June]

Dosage_June:
[image: i.stack.imgur.com/OVCxr.png]

Comment: Doing an update on a table using a where on another table doesn't make sense.

Comment: If you want to use a row from rawdosingjune to update a row in Dosage_June, you need a JOIN.

Comment: Could you please update your question with full table columns?

Comment: I added the table images in answer -1 below

Comment: The INNER JOIN added the data to every row. The tables are as follows: Dosage_June
rawdosingjune

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVCxr.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm4t3.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your tables, `Dosage_June.wellname` & `rawdosingjune.well` is the unique link therefore the `INNER JOIN` can use it for their `ON` condition.

Something like this should work:

```
UPDATE Dosage_June INNER JOIN rawdosingjune 
    ON Dosage_June.wellname=rawdosingjune.well
   SET Dosage_June.Corrosion_Basis = rawdosingjune.DosageBasis 
 WHERE rawdosingjune.corrosion = 'TRUE';
```

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

It should not be surprising that trying to use a `WHERE` clause that names a table not selected by the query, will not work.

In the case of your `SELECT`, it's valid, because you name a row that's part of the query.

In the case of your `UPDATE`, it's a completely unrelated row that the engine has no idea what to do with.

Instead, name a row that's actually part of the table(s) you're operating on.

Comment: That's impossible to know, without information about your schema and about what  you are attempting to accomplish. Unfortunately, you did not see fit to provide us with that information.

Comment: The INNER JOIN added the data to every row. The tables are as follows: Dosage_June
rawdosingjune

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVCxr.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm4t3.png

Comment: No, add the required detail into your question, as text, in the form of an [mcve].